# Android/Firebase Trying to show nested objects retrieved from Firebase in adapter

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to show a list of songs on a recyclerview in android, nothing too fancy. something like this:

---

Song1

in Album a

---

-Song2

in Album a

---

-Song3

in Album b

---

So far so good; also, my firebase db looks something like this (in my app, a song cannot be on two albums, so bear with me)

```
songs:
   -idSong1:
      description:"Song1"
      album: idAlbumA
   -idSong2:
      description:"Song2"
      album: idAlbumA
   -idSong3:
      description:"Song3"
      album: idAlbumB
albums:
   -idAlbumA:
      description:"Album a"
   -idAlbumB:
      description:"Album b"
```

Okay, enter Android adapters. I set a firebase valueListener to songs, retrieve all of them and pass them on to the adapter. The problem is, I still don't have the description of their albums. 
Let me clarify, I do have the id's of the albums, but I'm forced to set a value listener of every item to find out the album description. I'm not familiar with firebase but it doesn't take much to know that that can't be right. I would be setting and removing listener a lot when the user scrolls through the song list.

There is a high chance I might be approaching this whole thing the wrong way. So any kind of advice is welcome.

Lastly, I want to congratulate the guys at firebase for such an amazing product!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out what I was trying to do was to simply do a JOIN between two nodes. and here's how it's done: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html